# What is the meaning of "implicit val" in a Scala class definition?

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm working on coming up to speed with Scala and am a little confused about usage of the keyword "**implicit**."

I think I understand the notion of implicit parameters, where the parameters are not explicitly passed in, Scala will search for a value of the correct type (within the calling scope).

I'm confused with the use of "**implicit val**."

Consider the following code snippet:

```
case class DemoApp() {
   implicit val foo = CustomerFoo()
}
```

Does this have to do with parameters passed into the DemoApp() class constructor?

Can someone please clarify?

Thx, JohnB

Comment: It just creates a `val` called **foo** whose value is a `CustomerFoo()` and such value is an implicit value inside its scope. So I guess that either some other functionalities inside the case class call methods that require an implicit of such type, or that after instantiating the class you do something like `import instance._` so you bring the implicit in scope, or maybe that value shouldn't need to be implicit at all. Try commenting the implicit and see what happens.

Comment: See https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> think I understand the notion of implicit parameters, where the parameters are not explicitly passed in,

This is just the other side of the coin.

> Scala will search for a value of the correct type (within the calling scope).

Yes, but it will not just take *any* random value. *Only* values that are explicitly marked `implicit`.

There are four uses of an `implicit` modifier, which are related in pairs.

One pair is related to *implicit parameters*. When applied to a parameter in a parameter list, `implicit` means "this argument does not need to be supplied explicitly, it can be searched in the context of the call". When applied to a `val` or an `object`, in turn, it means "this value can be passed as an implicit argument".

The other pair is related to *implicit conversions*. When `implicit` is applied to a method definition of a method with one parameter, it means "whenever you need a value of the return type, but you only have a value of the parameter type, you can use this method to convert from the argument value to the return value".

E.g. if I have something like this:

```scala
implicit def string2Tuple2(s: String): (Int, Int) = {
  val l = s.split(",")
  (l(0).toInt, l(1).toInt)
}
```

Then, whenever Scala expects a `(Int, Int)`, I can also pass a `String` instead, and Scala knows that it can call `string2Tuple` to convert it:

```
val m = Map.empty[Int, Int]

m + "2,3"
//=> val res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(2 -> 3)
```

This is of course a stupid example. A more useful example is the *enrich-my-library idiom*, where we create a new class that augments an existing class with some new functionality, and then provide an implicit conversion from the old type to the enriched type:

```scala
class HelloString(s: String) {
  val hello = "Hello " + s + " World"
}

implicit def string2HelloString(s: String) = new HelloString(s)

"beautiful".hello
//=> val res2: String = Hello beautiful World
```

This is where the second use for the `implicit` modifier comes in. An `implicit` class is simply syntactic sugar for a wrapper class + an implicit conversion, meaning the above is exactly equivalent to:

```scala
implicit class string2HelloString(s: String) {
  val hello = "Hello " + s + " World"
}
```

There you have it, the four uses of the `implicit` modifier in two related pairs.